# setcontentview(layout) is not being set inside the if conditions checking the count of a cursor object, they are being skipped

Tags: java, android

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SQLiteDatabase db1;
    EditText passcode, lockcode, username, password,enterpassword;
    Button setcode, signin,enter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        passcode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpasscode);
        lockcode=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editlockcode);
        setcode=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btncode);



        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        String query = "SELECT * FROM Profile";
        Cursor cursor = db.getCursorForQuery(query);
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
        {
            Dialog dialogbox=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialogbox.setContentView(R.layout.profiledetails);
            username=(EditText)dialogbox.findViewById(R.id.usernameid);
            password=(EditText)dialogbox.findViewById(R.id.passwordid);
            signin=(Button)dialogbox.findViewById(R.id.signinbutton);
            dialogbox.setCancelable(false);
            signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String name=username.getText().toString();
                    String password1=password.getText().toString();
                    if(name.trim().length()>0 || password1.trim().length()>0) {

                        db.addprofile(name, password1);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter something",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        else if(cursor.getCount()!=0)
        {
            final Dialog dialogbox2=new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialogbox2.setContentView(R.layout.enterpassword);
            enterpassword=(EditText)dialogbox2.findViewById(R.id.idpassword);
            enter=(Button)dialogbox2.findViewById(R.id.btnenter);
            dialogbox2.setCancelable(false);
            enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String permpassword=enterpassword.getText().toString();
                    if(permpassword.trim().length()>0)
                    {
                        Cursor c=db1.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Profile WHERE _PASSCODE='" + permpassword + "'",null);
                        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            dialogbox2.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid attempt",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        setcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String passcode1=passcode.getText().toString();
                String lockcode1=lockcode.getText().toString();
                if(passcode1.trim().length()>0 || lockcode1.trim().length()>0) {
                    db.insert(passcode1, lockcode1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"please enter something",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So here is what I want, when I run the application first the query will be stored inside a cursor and it's count is checked

```
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Profile";
    Cursor cursor = db.getCursorForQuery(query);
    if (cursor.getCount() == 0)
    {
      .......
      //The layout will be set to 
       dialogbox.setContentView(R.layout.profiledetails);
      //
      ...
    }
```

Otherwise if the count is not 0, then the layout will be set to

```
     dialogbox2.setContentView(R.layout.enterpassword);
```

Instead both of the conditions are being skipped and the view is simply set to

```
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

which I have set initially.

When I first run the application, the SELECT query must obviously return a 0, but when I converted the getcount() into a String and printed it using Toast to find what the query returns, the value is greater than 0, 35 exactly, which is weird as I have not yet inserted anything into the table. Either way both of the if conditions are being skipped.

Here is the DBAdapter.java file which inherited the Sqlliteopenhelper class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


    Context context1;
    private  static  final int Database_Version=1;
    private  static final  String Database_Name="MyDatabase";
    private  static  final String Table_Passcode="Passcode";
    public static final String COLUMN_Passcode = "_PASSCODE ";
    private  static  final String Table_Lockcode="Lockcode";
    public static final String COLUMN_Lockcode = "_LOCKCODE ";
    private  static  final String Table_Profile="Profile";
    public static final String COLUMN_Username = "_USERNAME ";
    public static final String COLUMN_Password = "_PASSWORD ";

    public   DBAdapter(Context context) {

        super(context, Database_Name,null,Database_Version);
        this.context1=context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db=getWritableDatabase();
        String query="CREATE TABLE " + Table_Passcode + "(" + COLUMN_Passcode + " INTEGER NOT NULL )";
        db.execSQL(query);
        String query2="CREATE TABLE "+ Table_Lockcode + "(" + COLUMN_Lockcode + " INTEGER NOT NULL )";
        db.execSQL(query2);
        String query3="CREATE TABLE "+ Table_Profile+ "(" +COLUMN_Username + " VARCHAR NOT NULL, " + COLUMN_Password + " VARCHAR NOT NULL)" ;
        db.execSQL(query3);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Table_Passcode);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Table_Lockcode);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+Table_Profile);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void insert(String pass,String lock) {
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + Table_Passcode + "VALUES" + "(" + pass + ");");

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + Table_Lockcode + "VALUES" + "(" + lock + ");");
    }


    public void addprofile(String name, String pass2) {
        // ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Profile(_USERNAME,_PASSWORD) VALUES('"+ name + "' ,'"+ pass2+ "');");

    }


    public Cursor getCursorForQuery(String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery(query,null);
    }
}
```

Here is the xml layout files whose views have not been set.

profiledetails.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/colorRed" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/usernameid"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_marginLeft="-240dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:id="@+id/passwordid"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <Button

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signinbutton"
        android:text="Sign In"

        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

enterpassword.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorRed">
<EditText
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:hint=" ENTER PASSWORD"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/idpassword"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ENTER"
        android:id="@+id/btnenter"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is obviously a logical error. Can someone please help me to find what I'm missing. I'm just a novice programmer.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html:

The Dialog class is the base class for dialogs, but you should avoid instantiating Dialog directly.

Maybe you should create a new class for your dialogs that extend DialogFragment.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

In the OnCreateView for the DialogFragment, you can set the view.

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.somelayout, null);

    // some code here

    return inflatedView;
}
}
```

Then in the activity call the show() function when you need to.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (cursor blah blah) {
        MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
    }
}
```

As a bonus, right click you main package in android studio and select "reformat code".  <- that one's on the house.